# older sign for silence?

Tags: sheet-music, mozart

This is a manuscript from Mozart.

Can anyone confirm that the sign that's circled is a silence and provide a bit more background about that symbol?

[image]

Comment: Using simple maths it is a rest. Basically, as long as one can determine how long that 1st note is (not easy!) the rest (sic) of that bar is silent.

Comment: A sign for silence is called a "rest".

Comment: A relatively easy way to confirm is to look up the "modern" sheet music for the same piece. imslp.org is likely to have several versions available.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed an old sign for a crotchet/quarter rest.

Here for comparison is a bar from Mozart's Fantasia in c minor, K475, published in Vienna by Artaria:

[image: Fantasia in c minor, K475]

Comment: A quaver rest sign back to front.